# Low accuracy with change to TensorFlow Cifar10 example

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, image-recognition, object-detection

I am trying to modify the network structure provided by Cifar10 in TensorFlow. Typically, I added another convolution layer (conv12) after the first convolution layer (conv1). No matter how I set the filter (I tried all 1x1, 3x3, 5x5) and whether using weight decay or not, having a new layer will decrease the accuracy to below than 10%. This is equivalent to a random guess in Cifar10 since there are 10 classes.

The code structure is as following, I don't modify any other part of the cifar except setting the size of input image to be 48x48 (instead of 24x24). I guess the input size should not matter.

Note that the conv12 is a depthwise convolution layer because I want to add just a linear layer after the conv1 layer in order to minimize the change to the original code. Doing that I expected that the accuracy should be similar to the original version, but it decreases to around 10%. (I also tried a normal convolution layer but it didn't work also.)

```
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel1 = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                         stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel1, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases1 = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias1 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_1, biases1)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias1, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)


  with tf.variable_scope('conv12') as scope:
    kernel12 = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[1, 1, 64, 1],
                                         stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    #conv_12 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, kernel12, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    conv_12 = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(conv1, kernel12, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases12 = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias12 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_12, biases12)        
    conv12 = tf.nn.relu(bias12)
    _activation_summary(conv12)

  pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv12, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                     padding='SAME', name='pool1')
.....
```

Could someone please tell me what wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your second convolution:

```
kernel12 = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[1, 1, 64, 1]
```

is taking the depth-64 output of the previous layer and squeezing it down to a depth-1 output.  That doesn't seem like it will match with whichever code you have following this (if it's `conv2` from the [cifar example from TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py), then it definitely isn't going to work well, because that one expects a depth-64 input.)

Perhaps you really wanted `shape=[1, 1, 64, 64]`, which would simply add an extra "inception-style" 1x1 convolutional layer into your model?

Comment: Nope, I made a depthwsie_conv layer. The last value in the tuple is the channel_multiplier, so 1 here would make the output have a depth of 64. I also tried a normal convolution layer which has a filer of [1,1,64,64] as you suggested (you can see the commented-off line) but it also doesn't work. So I still assume this is not the source of the problem I am having.

Comment: Oh!  So you did - I missed that.  hmmmm.